# CollectionView Cell gets shifted to right after horizontal Scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView Cell that is of the same size of my CollectionView i.e. one Cell at a time is displayed on the screen and I want minimum separation of 10 between cells, the problem is when I scroll the cell the cells aren't properly fitting the whole screen, and the shifting of cell is increased after every scroll. (Check screenshots for better understanding)

[image: This is 3rd cell]

[image: This is 6th cell]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have set `pagingEnabled` for the collection view. It inherits this property from `UIScrollView` (because `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`).

The problem is that the collection view uses its own width (320 points in your post) as the width of a page. Each of your cells is the same width as the collection view, but then you have a 10 point “gutter” between the cells. This means that the distance from the left edge of cell 0 to the left edge of cell 1 is 320 + 10 = 330 points. So when you scroll to show cell 1, the collection view stops scrolling at offset 320 (its own width), but cell 1 actually starts at offset 330.

The easiest fix is probably to turn off `pagingEnabled` and implement paging yourself by overriding `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)` in your collection view delegate, like this:

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    guard let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }

    let pageWidth = scrollView.bounds.size.width + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing

    let currentPageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
    let maxPageNumber = CGFloat(collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) ?? 0)

    // Don't turn more than one more page when decelerating, and don't go beyond the first or last page.
    var pageNumber = round(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / pageWidth)
    pageNumber = max(0, currentPageNumber - 1, pageNumber)
    pageNumber = min(maxPageNumber, currentPageNumber + 1, pageNumber)
    targetContentOffset.pointee.x = pageNumber * pageWidth
}
```

You'll also want to set the item size to match the device screen size, and set the deceleration rate to fast:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    guard let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout, let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
    flowLayout.itemSize = collectionView.bounds.size

    collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
}
```

Result:

[image: demo]

Comment: thank you for the solution and great explanation @robmayoff , its working smoothly now

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have not taken the `minimum separation of 10` while setting width of the cell(320). Hence this `10` is getting accumulated each time to scroll.

So you have to subtract 10 out of 320 while setting the width, so the width should be 310 IMO.

Comment: I might not be accurate with my calculation, but the minimum spacing accumulation is the reason, so you have to take that into consideration.