# IOS/Objective-C: Slide updated view in from right on swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I would like to emulate the swipe to left to show next picture seen in the photos app, among other places so that the new picture slides in from right to left using animation.

However, in my case, the view has more than one photo. It has a caption as well.

I am able to do this without animation by just updating the photo and text upon swipe.  This just changes the photo and caption on screen, however, without the right to left animation technique.

Is there a way to show the old view moving to the left while the new updated view moves in from the right.

The following moves the view to the left but renders the screen black as nothing is put in its place.

```
//In handleSwipe called by gesture recognizer

  CGRect topFrame = self.view.frame;
        topFrame.origin.x = -320;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
 self.view.frame = topFrame; _myImage=newImage;
_mycaption=newcaption;} completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:**
The view in question is a detail view that you get to from a tableview through a segue. It currently already uses a scrollview for vertical scrolling as the content can exceed a single screen in the vertical dimension.

I have found a way to get the old photo and caption to move left and the new to come in from right using a completion block, however, it is less than satisfactory, because there is a gap between the two actions when the screen is black.  This seems endemic to completion approach because new image does not start to move until old image has completed moving.

```
 - (IBAction)swipedLeft:(id)sender
     {

     CGRect initialViewFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect movedToLeftViewFrame = CGRectMake(initialViewFrame.origin.x - 375, initialViewFrame.origin.y, initialViewFrame.size.width, initialViewFrame.size.height);
     CGRect movedToRightViewFrame = CGRectMake(initialViewFrame.origin.x + 375, initialViewFrame.origin.y, initialViewFrame.size.width, initialViewFrame.size.height);

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
     animations:^{self.view.frame = movedToLeftViewFrame;
//above moves old image out of view.
}
                      completion:^(BOOL finished)
      {
          self.view.frame = movedToRightViewFrame;
          [self loadNextItem];//changes pic and text.
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                           animations:^{self.view.frame = initialViewFrame;
//moves new one in
}
                           completion:nil];
      }];
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways to build this using existing components:

- `UIPageViewController` (see DuncanC's answer).
- `UICollectionView` with `pagingEnabled` set to true. Use a full-screen-sized cell and a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with `scrollDirection` set to horizontal.
- `UICollectionView` as above, but instead of setting `pagingEnabled` to true, implement `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` in your delegate. This allows you to have a gutter between each cell while still having each cell fill the screen. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43414498/77567).

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.)

Comment: The view controller in question is a detail view from a master table and is a UIViewController that inherits from a generic UIViewController I created that contains some generic methods used by all UIViewControllers.  In addition, the VC has some methods of its own that I need. Would you suggest I change its form to a UICollectionView or UIPageView.  Or should I segue to a new UICollectionView or UIPageView that then loads the UIVC displaying the image and caption?

Comment: `UICollectionView` is a view, not a view controller. You can set your view controller up as its data source and delegate.

Comment: Awesome.  I guess I should have known that.  Thx!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a `UIPageViewController`, and manage each image/set of images as a separate view controller.

A page view controller supports either a page curl style transition or a slide transition. You'd want the slide transition.

Comment: There can be hundreds of images and captions as they are drawn from a database (core data).  Can I just have one view controller that cycles through them all?

Comment: The fact that you can have hundreds of images is an argument FOR a page view controller. It manages view controllers in the same way that a table view manages cells. It only creates the child view controllers as needed.

Comment: There is a sample app "PhotoScroller" bundled with Xcode that demonstrates using a page view controller to scroll through high-res images. Unfortunately it's old and written in Objective-C, so it might not be that useful.

Comment: Hundreds of images means you should definitely use something that loads content on demand: `UIPageViewController` or `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @robmayoff, you put it better than I did.

Comment: Ok. I will give this try.

Answer (score 0):

It's ScrollView+PageControl
I hope it can help you.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        self.scrollView.delegate =self;
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =NO;
        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled =YES;
        self.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(ViewWidth*VIewCount, ViewHeight);
        [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];


        self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
        self. pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =NO;
        [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
        self. pageControl.numberOfPages = VIewCount;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              multiplier:1.0f
                                                                constant:0.0f]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[self.scrollView(width)]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:@{@"width":@(ViewWidth)}
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.scrollView)]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[self.scrollView(height)]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:@{@"height":@(HEIGHT_VIEW)}
                                                                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.scrollView)]];
         
       
      
     
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_scrollView]-5-[pageControl(15)]"
                                                                          options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.scrollView, self.pageControl)]];
//[imgArr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:...]];
        for (NSInteger index = 0; index<ViewCount; index++) {
            UIImageView *addSubview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(index*ViewWidth, 0, ViewWidth, ViewHeight)];
   // addSubView.image = [imgArr objectAtIndex:index];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:addSubview];
        }
    }
     
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        NSInteger index = currentOffset / ViewWidth;
         
        if (currentOffset % ViewWidth == 0) {
            pageControl.currentPage = index;
        }

    }
```